# ROME : Unable to get full description of post for a feed

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am parsing feed from http://feeds.feedburner.com/Commercial_LCD_Monitors. But while getting description of each post I got few lines and then it gets truncated with ending  **[...]** characters.

eg.

Stand out from the crowds with a higher  level of professionalism with the L305 mobile data projector. The 3000:1  ANSI lumens and advanced 3-chip LCD technology delivers images that are  of the highest quality, realistic and sharp. Colours are not only **[...]**

Can anyone explain what is the issue and possible resolution if any?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

The feed only provides a truncated description.  You'll either have to find another feed with a longer description or build something to retrieve the content from each item.